# Why does the video player's size change when I add a poster image?

Tags: html, css

I've seen many posts on this but when I add a poster image to the video element it changes the size of the video player.

```
<video src="/video.mp4" poster="/image.jpeg" class="videoPlayer" controls playsinline />

.videoPlayer {
  cursor: pointer;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img, video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

img, svg, video, canvas, audio, iframe, embed, object {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What could the reasons be that the video size is changing based on the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [intrinsic size](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#concept-video-intrinsic-width) of the `<video>` element is determined by its current frame.
When the image from the poster attribute is displayed, this "current frame" is the [*poster frame*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#poster-frame). So the *poster frame* is what determines the `<video>`'s intrinsic size.

In the absence of an other rule setting the video size (e.g the `width` or `height` attributes or CSS rules), this intrinsic size is what sets the display size of the element.